# Disable Delete/Edit On Header in TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using expanding sections to show/hide tableView rows underneath a header, but would like to exclude the headers from any tableView delete/editing options.

[image]

The header is just a custom cell:

```
   if indexPath.row == 0 { //"0" indicates the beginning of each section
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
   }
```

But since the headers and regular cells are all in the same tableView, I don't see a way to exclude the headers from any edits.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to implement `canEditRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.row != 0
}
```

Comment: You would not believe how long I've been searching for this solution. Thank you @vadian